# What is C# exclusive or `^` usage?

Tags: c#, operators, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

Can anyone explain this operator with a good example?

I know what this operator is. I mean a real-life example.

Comment: Simple search:
https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: I gave 3 in my answer.  There are about a dozen on the wiki page.

Comment: For the first time in my entire programming career, I've found a use for the XOR operator. Having ^ for Math.Pow() would have been a MUCH better use of the symbol.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is an implementation of the the logical operation `exclusive disjunction`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

> Exclusive disjunction is often used for bitwise operations. Examples:
>
> - 1 xor 1 = 0
> - 1 xor 0 = 1
> - 0 xor 1 = 1
> - 0 xor 0 = 0
> - 1110 xor 1001 = 0111 (this is equivalent to addition without carry)
>
> As noted above, since exclusive disjunction is identical to addition modulo 2, the bitwise exclusive disjunction of two n-bit strings is identical to the standard vector of addition in the vector space (Z/2Z)^4.
>
> In computer science, exclusive disjunction has several uses:
>
> - It tells whether two bits are unequal.
> - It is an optional bit-flipper (the deciding input chooses whether to invert the data input).
> - It tells whether there is an odd number of 1 bits ( is true iff an odd number of the variables are true).

(and a whole ton of other uses)

Answer (score 14):

For example, like this:

```
var result = a ^ b;

result          a        b
--------------------------------
true            true    false
true            false   true
false           true    true
false           false   false
```

Answer (score 7):

For "exclusive or" to evaluate to true one and only one operand has to be true.

```
foo ^ bar
```

is equivalent to

```
(foo && !bar) || (!foo && bar)
```

Comment: and @shenhengbin your answers about evaluating boolean values with the exclusive or operator made me wonder: isn't doing `foo ^ bar` equivalent to `foo != bar` as well then?

Answer (score 2):

When using XOR, the statement only evaluates to true if only ONE of the compared statements is true. So:

```
bool foo = true;
bool bar = false;
if (foo ^ bar) { bar = true;} // this evaluates to true 
bool baz = foo ^ bar; // This evaluates to false, since both statements are now true.
```

Answer (score 1):

A programming language's reference is always the best place to look for the definitions of operators.

In this case, MSDN is the most appropriate definition for a C# operator.

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Binary ^ operators are predefined for
>   the integral types and bool. For
>   integral types, ^ computes the bitwise
>   exclusive-OR of its operands. For bool
>   operands, ^ computes the logical
>   exclusive-or of its operands; that is,
>   the result is true if and only if
>   exactly one of its operands is true.

An example is also listed.

Answer (score 1):

XOR is a common boolean operator and has nothing unique to it in C#.
I suggest reading a little about boolean algebra to learn what it is used for with 1 bit,
then check what you get when you do (a XOR b) XOR b with any two numbers or characters a and b.